# Kubernetes networking internet-pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microk8s

I have an application that the management wants to migrated from **Docker** to **K8s**.

This application is like a blackbox from our point of view, and expect to communicate with a database over `port 5993` using the `gRPC` protocol.
In Docker I simply execute:

`docker run -p 5993:5993 ...`

And everything works as expected. I am a newby in K8s and my question is how can I move this setup in `K8s` properly?
I've lost a lot of time reading about `port-forward`, `Services`, `NodePort` but I do not understand what is the correct approach and which solution has to be used.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but application deployment and application exposure, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

As you can write docker run command; presumed you can construct a docker compose for the blackbox system, you can then start with [kompose](https://kompose.io/%5D) to convert your docker compose to k8s manifest. Note the converted spec is not always 100% runnable but it will give you an head start in this case.